# Config XML file in React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I add config.xml file in react native?

I checked my existing projects of react-native, there is no config.xml file in res folder.

Should I use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config)?

Comment: For what do you want to handle config.xml file? It rings a bell something like I use to do in Android Studio, then if you are searching for a file related with Android, you could find it in the Android folder of the project. Anyway you can open the project like if it could be Android Studio project opening the folder "Android" with Android Studio.

Comment: I want to do some settings in config file, I want to add some preferences for splash screen.

Comment: Then open the project with Android Studio. You should find it there!